# Export database table with data

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to export database table with data using MySQL workbench? Because I am using the reverse and forward engineer and somehow, it only export empty table without any data inside. Here is the website that teach me to export:

[enter link description here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/MySQL-Workbench.html)

Can somebody please teach me? And I know I kinda posted this thread in a wrong place. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the mySQL plugins for excel. Not perfect but works.

Comment: how should I do that? Can give me some guide?

Answer (score 0):

The export should be default include the table data. Make sure that **Skip table data (no-data)** in the options sub-panel is unchecked before you start the export.

If that doesn't work, try reverse engineering your database by going to the menu option **Database > Reverse Engineer** and complete the steps.

After you've reverse engineered your database, go to **File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script.**

Under **SQL Options**, check the box **Generate INSERT statements** for Tables and then continue the export process.

Comment: So I need create a script? or how should I do that?

Comment: Open MySQL Workbench > Home > Manage Import / Export (Right bottom) / Select Required DB > Advance Exports Options Tab >Complete Insert [Checked] > Start Export.

Comment: But can I do this with the reverse and forward engineer? Because I cannot click on the manage import/export on the main page. something wrong with my laptop

Comment: In the forward enginner, do I need to check the generate insert statement for tables? But I cannot see any data inside the script tho

Answer (score 0):

Use [server administration] > [DATA EXPORT]
[image]

Comment: There something wrong with my WMI interface which I cannot use the server admin to export. So I only can use the reverse and forward engineer

Comment: Try use to root login.